# Concurrent SVN updates on the same workspace

Tags: svn, svn-lock

In my company we use Jenkins to build our C++ applications. As the projects are strongly interconnected and we use a hierarchical make structure, we check out the whole source code as one big workspace.

We then use different Jenkins projects that do updates on different subfolders of the same workspace before building and sometimes the projects are built at the same time. With Subversion 1.6 that worked without problems, however with Subversion 1.7 we often get the following errors:

> Workspace appear to be locked, so getting a fresh workspace

I think it's because subversion 1.7 locks the whole workspace if an update is running (and 1.6 only locked the concerned subfolder).

Is there a way to do an SVN update without locking the subversion workspace in Subversion 1.7 ?  Best regards.

Comment: No, in SVN working copy 1.7 the whole working copy is locked because there's one .svn/wc.db database that keeps information about all paths. If you want several process to update the working copy, consider switching to 1.6 again.

Comment: Ouch! Another case of "this is as designed and the reason is <insert obscure implementation detail that users should not have to care about here>". :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  I think you're going to have to have have a jenkins job that updates the workspace for all projects, and then spawn the the other jobs which could build concurrently - but not update the working copy.